# Get all swing components in a container

Tags: java, swing, awt, jcomponent

I think we can use `jScrollPane.getComponents()` to get awt components of a jscrollpane. 
My question is: is there a way to get swing components of a container some how?

Comment: Swing components extend AWT components.  (So `getComponents()` reports both).

Comment: Often you're better off holding references to the important components rather than having to recurse through nested containers in order to find your needle in a haystack.

Comment: Note that so far the two answers given do not use recursion and will get you nothing but the JScrollPane's JViewport.

Comment: @Hovercraft (Monday morning, nitpicking time :-) its viewport_s_ (there can be several) and its scrollbars. Disagree with your other comment: if you need to often talk to a particular component its usually time to carefully re-think the design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Swing components extend JComponent.

```
Component[] comps = jScrollPane.getComponents();
ArrayList<JComponent> swingComps = new ArrayList<JComponent>();

for(Component comp : comps) {
     if(comp instanceof JComponent) {
          swingComps.add((JComponent) comp);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `getComponents` then test to see if it is an instance of `JComponent`. A method would be like:

```
ArrayList jcomponents = new ArrayList();
for (Component c : container.getComponents())
{
      if (c instanceof JComponent)
      {
            jcomponents.add(c);
      }
 }
```

Comment: Which is essentially the same as the other answer, I did not see the other answer until after I posted mine.